how to fix function component cannot be given refs while using framer motion useAnimate hook?


Navbar component code

import Humburger from "./ui/Humburger";
const navlins = ["HOME", "PAGES", "PRODUCTS", "ARTICLES", "CONTACT"];
const Navbar = () => {
  const [isNavbarActive, setIsNavbarActive] = useState(false);
  const toogleNavbar = () => setIsNavbarActive(!isNavbarActive);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="relative bg-white h-[4.5rem] z-20">
        <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-between items-center px-4">
          <Image
            width={120}
            height={70}
            src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/65478d390c8996a757a4faaa/65c4aacccb9a41d80d0d66f7_Stride-logo-dark.svg"
            alt="nav-logo"
          />
          <div className="hidden">
            <ul className="flex w-full border border-green-500">
              <li>Home</li>
              <li>Pages</li>
              <li>Product</li>
              <li>Article</li>
              <li>contact</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
            <div className="relative h-10 w-10 p-2">
              <Image
                className="z-0 inset-0"
                src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/65478d390c8996a757a4faaa/659e5cb3e032b694713f63c0_Add%20to%20basket.svg"
                width={20}
                height={20}
                alt="cart-icon"
              />
              <div className="z-20 absolute shadow-xl top-1 -right-[2px] bg-gray-200 text-black rounded-full text-[0.6em] h-[1.1rem] w-[1.1rem] grid place-content-center font-bold">
                5
              </div>
            </div>

            <button className="border flex items-center justify-center border-slate-400 hover:focus-within:none bg-black text-white rounded-full px-4 py-1.5 hover:bg-white transition-all ease-in hover:text-black">
              Login
            </button>

            <Humburger onClick={() => setIsNavbarActive(!isNavbarActive)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <AnimatePresence mode="popLayout">
        {isNavbarActive && <NavbarDropdown />}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

const NavbarDropdown = () => {
  const dropdownVariants = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
    enter: {
      opacity: 1,
      height: "14rem",
      transition: {
        ease: [0.83, 0, 0.17, 1],
        duration: 0.5,
        staggerChildren: 0.1,
        staggerDirection: 1,
        delayChildren: 0.2,
        // Stagger the li children after the dropdown opens
      },
    },
    exit: {
      height: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: [0.83, 0, 0.17, 1],
        staggerChildren: 0.1, // Stagger the li children on exit as well
        staggerDirection: -1,
        delay: 0.3,
        // Reverse the direction (exit from bottom to top)
        // Delay before shrinking the dropdown after the li items
      },
    },
  };

  const liVariants = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: -50,
    },

    enter: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },

    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: -50,
      transition: {
        ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={dropdownVariants}
      initial="initial"
      animate="enter"
      exit="exit"
      className="absolute origin-top top-[4.6rem] w-full bg-white drop-shadow-lg"
    >
      <motion.ul className="space-y-5 px-3">
        {navlins.map((navlin, index) => (
          <motion.li
            custom={index}
            key={index}
            variants={liVariants} // Apply variants to each li item
            className="text-gray-600 text-[1em] font-normal flex items-center gap-5"
          >
            {navlin}
            {index === 0 || index === 1 ? (
              <IoMdArrowDown size={24} color="gray" />
            ) : (
              <></>
            )}
          </motion.li>
        ))}
      </motion.ul>
    </motion.div>
  );
};


Humburger Component code

"use client";
import { useAnimate } from "framer-motion";
import React, { forwardRef, useState } from "react";

const Humburger = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, { onClick: () => void }>(
  ({ onClick }, forwardedRef) => {
    const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
    const [isHumburgOpen, setIsHumburgOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState(false);

    const animateHumburger = async () => {
      if (isAnimating) return null;

      setIsAnimating(!isAnimating);
      onClick();
      if (!isHumburgOpen) {
        animate(
          "#top",
          {
            y: "0.45rem",
          },
          {
            ease: [0.36, 0, 0.66, -0.56],
            duration: 0.5,
          }
        );
        await animate(
          "#bottom",
          {
            y: `-${0.45}rem`,
            opacity: 0,
          },
          {
            ease: [0.36, 0, 0.66, -0.56],
            duration: 0.5,
          }
        );
        animate(
          "#top",
          {
            rotate: "136deg",
          },
          {
            ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
            duration: 0.5,
          }
        );
        animate(
          "#middle",
          {
            rotate: "43deg",
          },
          {
            ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
            duration: 0.5,
          }
        );
        setIsHumburgOpen(!isHumburgOpen);
      } else {
        animate(
          "#top",
          {
            rotate: "0deg",
          },
          {
            ease: [0.36, 0, 0.66, -0.56],
            duration: 0.5,
          }
        );
        await animate(
          "#middle",
          {
            rotate: "0deg",
          },
          {
            ease: [0.36, 0, 0.66, -0.56],

            duration: 0.5,
          }
        );
        animate(
          "#top",
          {
            y: "0rem",
          },
          {
            ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
            duration: 0.5,
          }
        );
        await animate(
          "#bottom",
          {
            y: 0,
            opacity: 1,
          },
          {
            ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
            duration: 0.5,
          }
        );

        setIsHumburgOpen(!isHumburgOpen);
      }
      setIsAnimating(false);
    };
    return (
      <div ref={scope}>
        <a
          onClick={animateHumburger}
          className="hover:focus-within:outline-none hover:focus:outline-none flex flex-col items-end justify-center h-24 gap-1 mt-50 cursor-pointer"
        >
          <span
            id="top"
            className="origin-center h-[3px] w-6 bg-black  block rounded-full"
          ></span>
          <span
            id="middle"
            className="h-[3px] w-6  bg-black   rounded-full"
          ></span>
          <span
            id="bottom"
            className="h-[3px] w-4 bg-black  rounded-full"
          ></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

export default Humburger;


the function animateHumburger  is doing simply animating three vertical bar to a cross.
am using framermotion to animate and am using useAnimate hook where i have to pass scope to the main container and id to sub element through which i will use in useanimatehook to animate them.
after this humburger component is finished i have used it in navbar component but i get error .however the ref is being used in humburger component itself why i need to pass the useRef hook as suggested by chatgpt though it also didnot slove the problem .
with function component cannot be given refs what does it actually mean ??
even in react doc they have used in functional component or am i getting it wrong. please correct me and help me to solve the issue ??

.

Also give me solution to the problem how to fix this error


Which function component is trying to use or have a React ref passed to it? Can you [edit] to include the complete error message and accompanying stacktrace, and a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

humburger component is using ref  i.e it's reference is store in scope that comes from framer-motion useAnimate hook as you can see in the humburger component ..

Hamburger is only passing scope as a React ref to a div element, which is fine. I don't see any other ref usage in your code and I don't see an issue with what you have shared in your post. According to the first screenshot there's some problem in Navbar.

to create the same issue you can create a nextjs project first with ts tailwindcss
2. install framer-motion,reacticons and setup next.config.js file like copy paste nextjs config file from below which is in another commment.

create a navbar component and humburgercomponent
simply copy past the code from above to its corresponding file.
and simply run the project switch to developer mode use mobile view  not desktop.
click the humburger icon and view console.log .


const nextConfig = {
images: {
remotePatterns: [
{
protocol: "https",
hostname: "images.unsplash.com",
pathname: "",
},
{
protocol: "https",
hostname: "cdn.prod.website-files.com",
pathname: "",
},
{
protocol: "https",
hostname: "uploads-ssl.webflow.com",
pathname: "**",
},
],
},
};

Look at the error message and stacktrace, and then look at the relevant NavbarDropdown  code and see that NavbarDropdown  doesn't handle any refs passed to it.

The problem is that NavbarDropdown is not wrapped in forwardRef.
The docs state:

Custom component note: When using popLayout mode, any immediate child of AnimatePresence that's a custom component must be wrapped in React's forwardRef function, forwarding the provided ref to the DOM node you wish to pop out of the layout.

You are using a custom component (NavbarDropdown) as the immediate child of AnimatePresence and you are also using popLayout mode:
<AnimatePresence mode="popLayout">
    {isNavbarActive && <NavbarDropdown />}
</AnimatePresence>

So this constraint applies to you.
To fix, wrap NavbarDropdown with forwardRef and apply that ref on the element you want to "pop". I have assumed here it's the first element within NavbarDropdown.
const NavbarDropdown = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, {}>((props, ref) => {
  const dropdownVariants = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
    enter: {
      opacity: 1,
      height: "14rem",
      transition: {
        ease: [0.83, 0, 0.17, 1],
        duration: 0.5,
        staggerChildren: 0.1,
        staggerDirection: 1,
        delayChildren: 0.2,
        // Stagger the li children after the dropdown opens
      },
    },
    exit: {
      height: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: [0.83, 0, 0.17, 1],
        staggerChildren: 0.1, // Stagger the li children on exit as well
        staggerDirection: -1,
        delay: 0.3,
        // Reverse the direction (exit from bottom to top)
        // Delay before shrinking the dropdown after the li items
      },
    },
  };

  const liVariants = {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: -50,
    },

    enter: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
      transition: {
        ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },

    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: -50,
      transition: {
        ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1],
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      ref={ref}
      variants={dropdownVariants}
      initial="initial"
      animate="enter"
      exit="exit"
      className="absolute origin-top top-[4.6rem] w-full bg-white drop-shadow-lg"
    >
      <motion.ul className="space-y-5 px-3">
        {navlins.map((navlin, index) => (
          <motion.li
            custom={index}
            key={index}
            variants={liVariants} // Apply variants to each li item
            className="text-gray-600 text-[1em] font-normal flex items-center gap-5"
          >
            {navlin}
            {index === 0 || index === 1 ? (
              <IoMdArrowDown size={24} color="gray" />
            ) : (
              <></>
            )}
          </motion.li>
        ))}
      </motion.ul>
    </motion.div>
  );
});


thankyou so much i think it if i hadn't posted here it will take a weeks to figure it out on my own or may be more.... but i like what are the steps you took to find out the solution of the problem ... so that whenever in the future the problem aries i think i can be more carefull and tackle the error more easily ..... ,that will be big help for me.thankyou once again..
